# Is there a database of hotels that shows what loyalty systems they accept?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, loyalty-programs

When I travel I find it very difficult to find out whether I can accrue Delta or AA miles, or IHG or HHilton points. Often I have to call and talk to the hotel, and still sometimes the person on the phone is not trained and send "no" without knowing how to check.

Is there a good database online that lists major hotels, and what points and miles systems they are a part of?

Comment: Each of the major chains have their own list of brands, is that as simple as what you're after?

Comment: Also, don't forget that some hotel chains let you pick between either their own points scheme, or certain airline/related schemes, but only Hilton let you do both, and not all chains support all airlines

Answer (score 2):

While it's not a definitive list of all the combination and programs (I'm not convinced such a thing exists), [MillionMileSecrets has a pretty decent list](http://millionmilesecrets.com/mile-and-point-resources/hotel-reward-program-sign-up/) of Hotel Loyalty Programs:

> 1)  Choice Privileges - includes Ascend Collection, Cambria Suites,
>   Clarion,  Comfort Inn, Comfort Suites, EconoLodge, MainStay Suites,
>   Quality Inn, Rodeway Inn, Sleep Inn, and Suburban brand hotels.
>
> 2)  Club Carlson – includes Country Inns and Suites, Radisson,
>   Radisson Blu, Park Inn by Radisson,  and Park Plaza
>
> 3)  Hyatt Gold Passport - includes Andaz, Grand Hyatt, Hyatt, Hyatt
>   Place, Hyatt Regency, Hyatt Resorts,  Hyatt Summerfield Suites,  and
>   Park Hyatt brand hotels.
>
> 3)  Hilton HHonors - includes DoubleTree, Conrad,  Embassy Suites,
>   Hampton Inn, Hilton, Hilton Garden Inn, Home2Suites,  Homewood Suites,
>   and Waldorf Astoria brand hotels.
>
> 4)  Marriott Rewards - includes Marriott Hotels & Resorts, JW Marriott
>   Hotels & Resorts, Renaissance Hotels, Courtyard by Marriott, AC Hotels
>   by Marriott, Residence Inn by Marriott, Fairfield Inn & Suites by
>   Marriott,  TownePlace Suites by Marriott,  SpringHill Suites by
>   Marriott, The Ritz-Carlton Hotel Company L.L.C.,  ExecuStay, and
>   Marriott Executive Apartments Grand Residences by Marriott brands.
>
> 5)  IHG Rewards  - includes Candlewood Suites, Crowne Plaza,  Holiday
>   Inn, Holiday Inn Express, Hotel Indigo, Intercontinental Hotels &
>   Resorts, and Staybridge Suites brand hotels.
>
> 6)  Starwood Preferred Guest - includes Aloft, Element, Four Points,
>   Le Meredien, Sheraton,  St Regis,  The Luxury Collection, Westin and W
>   brand hotels.
>
> 7)  Wyndham Hotel Rewards – includes Baymont Inn, Days Inn, Hawthorne
>   Suites, Howard Johnson, Knights Inn, Microtel, Ramada, Super 8,
>   Travelodge, Wingate, Wyndham Hotels & Resorts, Wyndham Garden, and
>   Wyndham Grand Collection.

if we can find a more definitive list that's great, but after a while of searching this is the best I've found, even though there are already obvious gaps.